# T-SQL Multi Use Function to Replace SQL in Procedures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

Let's assume I have the same following code in three procedures:

```
    SELECT CASE
           WHEN [column1] LIKE '%/[a-z][a-z]-[a-z][a-z]/%' THEN REVERSE ( SUBSTRING ( REVERSE ( [column1] ) ,1,PATINDEX ( '%/%',REVERSE ( [column1] )) - 1 )) 
           WHEN [column1] LIKE '' THEN ISNULL ( NULLIF ( [column1],'' ) ,'(not set)' ) 
           ELSE 'Other'
           END AS ColumnReturned
FROM X
```

1) Is it possible to have a "function" instead of this piece of code stored somewhere else, in one place? So then I can call only:

```
SELECT myFunction (column1)
FROM X
```

in the procedures. So if I want to change the logic, I'd change it only in one place.

2) If I could have such function as per 1) point, can I have also multiple functions in one "file"? So I have list of different functions in one place? Then I'd be able to call:

```
SELECT functionList.myFunction1 (column1)
      ,functionList.myFunction2 (column2)
FROM X
```

Or the functions need to be separeated and only share scheme?

I am new to T-SQL functions so will be happy if you could point me some starting point.

Comment: test the performance difference before committing to this change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [basic syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) for what you want is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.YourFunction (@Column VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN  CASE
                WHEN @Column LIKE '%/[a-z][a-z]-[a-z][a-z]/%' 
                    THEN REVERSE ( SUBSTRING ( REVERSE ( @Column ) ,1,PATINDEX ( '%/%',REVERSE ( @Column )) - 1 )) 
                WHEN @Column LIKE '' 
                    THEN ISNULL ( NULLIF ( @Column,'' ) ,'(not set)' ) 
                    ELSE 'Other'
                END 
END
```

You would then just use:

```
SELECT dbo.YourFunction (x.column1) AS ColumnReturned
FROM X;
```

**HOWEVER**, scalar user defined functions can be a massive performance drain, and it may improve performance to convert it to an inline table valued function instead, so the function would be:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.YourFunction (@Column VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN  
(   SELECT  CASE
                WHEN @Column LIKE '%/[a-z][a-z]-[a-z][a-z]/%' 
                    THEN REVERSE ( SUBSTRING ( REVERSE ( @Column ) ,1,PATINDEX ( '%/%',REVERSE ( @Column )) - 1 )) 
                WHEN @Column LIKE '' 
                    THEN ISNULL ( NULLIF ( @Column,'' ) ,'(not set)' ) 
                    ELSE 'Other'
            END AS ColumnReturned
);
```

This makes calling the function a bit more complicated, but it is often worth it:

```
SELECT (SELECT f.ColumnReturned FROM dbo.YourFunction (x.column1) AS f) AS ColumnReturned
FROM X;
```

OR

```
SELECT f.ColumnReturned
FROM X
    CROSS APPLY dbo.YourFunction (x.Column1) AS f;
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Could you please also point me to some source where can I learn more about the "performance drain" you mentioned?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had put these in the answer. Here's a couple - [How to Make Scalar UDFs Run Faster (SQL Spackle)](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/91724/), [SQL Server Pro - Inline Scalar Functions](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/inline-scalar-functions)